# Groovy - combine two Maps with different columns

Tags: groovy

I have two <strike>`ArrayList`</strike> `Maps` defined. And I want to combined them in one.

```
def arrayL1 = [name: "Smith", age: "2"]
def arrayL2 = [school: "School1", address: "Address1"]
```

Expexted output:

```
newArray = [name: "Smith", age: "2", school: "School1", address: "Address1"]
```

Comment: They're maps not ArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below methods to add the two maps

> 1.Spread map operator

It allows you to inline the contents of a map into another map literal, like in the following example:

```
Map map1 = [name: "Smith", age: "2"]

Map map2 = [school: "School1", address: "Address1", *:map1]
```

Output :

```
map2 = [name: "Smith", age: "2", school: "School1", address: "Address1"]
```

> 2.Plus operator

```
Map mergedMap = map1 + map2
```

> 3.Plus method

```
Map mergedMap = map1.plus(map2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newArray = arrayL1.plus(arrayL2)
```

or

```
newArray = arrayL1 + arrayL2
```

should do the trick